# "Missing argument for parameter 'style' in call" error in creating system UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, swift

I don't understand why the compiler is asking for an argument to the style parameter in this system-style UIBarButtonItem initializer--it does not have that parameter in the first place. Help? Is this a bug with Swift?

```
class ExpensesViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var newExpenseBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: Selector("newExpenseBarButtonItemTapped:"))

    func newExpenseBarButtonItemTapped() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you ever get a valid answer for this?

Comment: @AaronBratcher Yes, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove the compiler error message:

```
class ExpensesViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var newExpenseBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd.value, 
                 target:self, action:Selector("newExpenseBarButtonItemTapped:"))

    func newExpenseBarButtonItemTapped() {

    }

}
```

`.Add` is not a valid value

Comment: What is this `.value` you're adding after `UIBarButtonSystemItem.UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`? Can't seem to get the error to go away for me :(

Comment: Failing for me as well, and when I try the initializer based on setting a title, it gives me an error that I am missing the landscape image parameter. Seems to get completely mixed up.

Answer (score 3):

No need to add the Selector verb for the action.

```
class ExpensesViewController: UIViewController {

lazy var newExpenseBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem( barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add,
                                                        target:self,
                                                        action:"newExpenseBarButtonItemTapped")


 func newExpenseBarButtonItemTapped() 
 {

 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `self` in the class scope, you will get a lot of weird compiler messages. It looks like swift compiler is not mature yet. Following code works fine with me on Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

```
class Foo {
    var playButton:UIBarButtonItem? = nil

    func initButtons(){
        self.playButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: Selector("doPlay:"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by making the button an implicitly unwrapped optional then initializing it later on.